# how do i insert expandable listview child item into sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new in android. I want to insert expandable listview child click item into sqlite database Any help please give me suggestion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, create the `Database` using `SQLiteOpenHeler` class and create the table. Add the columns in the table for what you want to save list item. After the database is ready, now you can insert into sqlitedatabase. For Example your List item is "Person" and person has first name and last name. Your table will contain first name and last name columns. On click you will do something like following:

```
Person person = list.get(position);

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("column_first_name", person.getFirstName());
values.put("column_last_name", person.getLastName());

getWriteableDatabase().insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why down voted? He is newbie and I advised him the steps??

Comment: Not my downvote, but his question does not follow the rules and guidelines for questions. Answering bad questions attracts more bad written questions, and I assume, therefor your answer was downvoted. ;)

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. I was just helping out.

Comment: i am using this effort getting null pointer exception.but i appreciate the effort